# Regular expression in Perl for email splitting

Tags: regex, perl, email-validation

I was asked by my peer that how you will look for last @`if more than one`@` is present.

Example:

```
j@ssi@aliencoders.com@..coding.com
```

So it should display `j@ssi@aliencoders.com` as username and  `..coding.com` as domain name.
Is there any one liner regex in Perl to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Email::Address.  These things are too hard for simple re's to do correctly.  Oops, didn't read op close enough, but this code works for splitting emails.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Address;

my $line = 'bill@example.com;joe@example.com';
my @addresses = Email::Address->parse($line);
for my $address (@addresses) {
  print $address->format, "\n";
}
```

Comment: It requires Email::Address to be installed before using it. By default it's not present. Otherwise, it's a cool module for all email validation work

Answer (score 8):

```
my ($username, $domain) = $str =~ /(.*)@(.*)/;
```

More information in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> By default, a quantified subpattern is "greedy", that is, it will
>   match as many times as possible (given a particular starting location)
>   while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the greedyness:

```
/(.*)@(.*)$/
```

The first part will take as much as it can until it encounters an @. The last part will take everything behind the @ until the end of the line.

Comment: How much efficient it is? I wrote the same thing but I was looking for any better solution where every such mail ids from a file can be filtered out.   Thanks Koneark for the regex :)

Comment: The only real answer to 'how efficient is it' is 'benchmark it', but compiling a simple regexp like that should not be a problem. Perl was practically made for regexps. If you think another solution (maybe index+substring? maybe split?) might be faster, benchmark those too :]

Answer (score 2):

quantifiers in Perl are greedy by default.  that means that they'll grab as much as possible.

what you want is a simple:

```
($username, $domain) = ($string =~ /(.*)@(.*)$/);
```

If you want to be 100% certain that the second part has no `@`, you can use:

```
($username, $domain) = ($string =~ /(.*)@([^@]*)$/);
```

Comment: Last line has something extra. well with greedy search, I don't think it has of any use...so your first code and second code has same effect. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$str='j@ssi@aliencoders.com@..coding.com';
$user=qw();
$domain=qw();
while($str=~m/\@/g){
    $user=$`;
    $domain=$';
}
print "user -> $user\n";
print "domain->$domain\n";
```

Comment: why bother initializing `$user` and `$domain`?

Comment: Thanks. and if u are using strict and warnings module both, you need to initialize so that you should get any errors or warnings.